# How do you pass data for selected cell using UITableView from ViewController A to ViewController B with MVVM?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mvvm, architecture

So at the moment I am creating a basic weather app list where if the cell is pressed, the data would be passed using the viewModel weathers array at the selected index from `ViewController A` (WeatherListViewController) to `ViewController B` (WeatherDetailsViewController). But Looking at WeathersDetailViewController, I have set the property var viewModel: Weather? to get access to its properties. Is this way wrong? And if so, whats the better way of accessing the data model, because I'm pretty sure this would not be mvvm due to accessing the model right away instead of `viewModel`.

```
struct Weather: Codable {

    let date: Int
    let description: String
    let maxTemperature: Double

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey  {
        case date = "time"
        case description = "summary"
        case maxTemperature = "temperatureMax"
    }
}
```

```
class WeatherListViewModel {

    private(set) var weathers = [Weather]()
    private var sessionProvider: URLSessionProvider

    init(sessionProvider provider: URLSessionProvider) {
        self.sessionProvider = provider
    }

    func addWeather(_ weatherModel: Weather) {
        weathers.append(weatherModel)
    }

    func numberOfRows(inSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return weathers.count
    }

    func modelAt(_ index: Int) -> Weather {
        return weathers[index]
    }

    func didSelect(at indexPath: Int) -> Weather {
        return weathers[indexPath]
    }   
}
```

// **didSelectRowAt method is inside ViewController A** (WeatherListViewController)

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedWeather = viewModel.didSelect(at: indexPath.row)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard.storyboard(storyboard: .weatherDetail)
        let viewController: WeatherDetailViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController()
        viewController.viewModel = selectedWeather
        navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }
```

// **And here is ViewController B**

```
class WeatherDetailsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private var imageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet private var cityLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private var temperatureLabel: UILabel!

    var viewModel: Weather?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .red
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "weather-image")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true

        dateLabel.text = viewModel?.date.toString()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
    } 
}
```

Comment: you have to use protocols

Comment: you are in right way